# Sloshy the Thawman: A simple bot for keeping Stack{Overflow,Exchange} chat rooms alive

Tags: app, chatbot

On https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and https://chat.stackexchange.com/, chat rooms will freeze after some two weeks of inactivity.  While this is fine and [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), some rooms are worth keeping around for a longer time for various reasons; for example, some communities have rooms which are useful for infrastructure, but which don't typically, or often, receive actual messages from live humans.  You don't want those to be frozen.

A common workaround is to (try to remember to) manually write something in the room from time to time, but this is obviously tedious and error-prone.

Enter [Sloshy the Thawman,](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/16115299/sloshy) a simple bot which logs in once per night (by way of a [dead simple Github Action](https://github.com/tripleee/sloshy/blob/master/.github/workflows/nightly.yml)) and checks a list of rooms for activity, and writes something in those which are close to the freezing point.

Sloshy's activity is logged in the [SOBotics room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), here is [a recent sample](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52535571#52535571):

[image: Screen shot from SObotics July 1st 02:17 AM]

This bot is a simple Python script, currently operated by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)<sup>1</sup>; for details, please refer to the bot's [Github project page.](https://github.com/tripleee/sloshy)

The bot does not particularly need the StackExchange API for anything, and so this post is merely an FYI and/or publicity stunt. (Technically, it just fetches the static chat transcript for the latest day for each room using `requests` and parses it with BeautifulSoup like any run of the mill Python scraper.)

Sloshy does not support secret rooms, for semi-obvious reasons. A closed-source configuration file could perhaps be deployed if there is a real need, but it's really not clear how that could be maintained without a separate project and then perhaps a separate bot identity.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the spirit of providing this service as infrastructure, they will be happy to make you a co-owner if you can convince them that you are interested in co-ownership out of care for the sites in the network.

Being able to debug Python code is an obvious plus; the bot itself is simple, and mainly relies on the [ChatExchange Python library](https://github.com/Manishearth/ChatExchange/), but there will probably be times when it helps if you can understand what it's doing.

Comment: Adding a comment here so you can ping me. Probably ping me, rather than the bot, if you have comments or questions. Thanks to @rene for guiding me in setting up this post.

Comment: @tripleee You could follow the post so you get pinged for answers too...

Comment: @Anonymous As a matter of fact I have, but that doesn't make me pingable if someone wants to address me in a comment, so I left a comment too.

Comment: The SOBotics room is in read mode for the duration of the moderation strike, so Sloshy is running in [his own room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233626/sloshy-the-thawman) for the time being.

Comment: @tripleee how to setup this bot for my room?

Comment: @PetLinux Simply create a PR in accordance with the instructions in the main [README](https://github.com/tripleee/sloshy/blob/master/README.md) on Github.

Comment: See also now https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63857339#63857339

Comment: Competing offer: https://stackapps.com/questions/10422/toasty-a-better-chat-antifreeze-bot