# Toasty: A better chat antifreeze bot

Tags: app, chatbot

#### About

Toasty is an antifreeze bot for the Stack Exchange chat system. It automatically sends messages in low-activity rooms to keep the system from freezing them for inactivity. Toasty is usable by any user with at least 200 network-wide reputation through its intuitive web interface.

Caveats:

- Toasty currently only supports https://chat.stackexchange.com, not https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com or https://chat.stackoverflow.com. Support for the other two sites is planned to be added soon.
- Toasty cannot antifreeze rooms that its bot user cannot access; this realistically means that the following cannot be antifrozen:

  - Private rooms
  - Rooms that are already frozen
  - Gallery rooms that Toasty is not allowed to access
- For Gallery rooms, Toasty's [bot user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/119710/toasty) must be allowed to send messages. If Toasty is unable to antifreeze a room, an error will be logged under the Runs tab on the room info page.
- <s>Due to an oversight with how rooms are stored, owners of a room that is being antifreezed by Toasty will not see the room in their room list unless they added it themself. (They will still be able to access and edit the room by going to its page directly.) This is planned to be fixed soon.</s> 
   **This issue is now fixed.** However, newly added ROs will need to wait for up to 24 hours for the bot to update its stored room list.
- Moderators may not be automatically granted the mod role upon creating an account due to an issue with how modship is checked. This is planned to be fixed soon. If you are a moderator and have not been automatically granted the mod role, ping Ginger in [the Toasty chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148706/i-cant-believe-its-not-botter). This *may* also cause users with 200+ reputation on only a few sites to be erroneously denied from creating an account, although this has not happened yet.

The antifreeze jobs run daily, at a randomly selected time within a 3-hour window centered on UTC midnight.

#### Screenshot:

[image: A screenshot of Toasty's index page]

#### Website

Find Toasty at https://toasty.ginger.rto.community

#### Contact:

Toasty was written entirely by me, Ginger. You can discuss it in its [dedicated chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148706/i-cant-believe-its-not-botter), which is also linked to in the footer.

#### License

Toasty is licensed under the Mozilla Public License 2.0.

#### Code

Toasty is written in Python (backend) and TypeScript (frontend), and uses [sechat](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/sechat/tree/v2) to communicate with chat. You can find the source at https://github.com/GingerIndustries/toasty.

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I try to log in: "400 Bad Request You seem to have encountered an error. Don't poke your nose where it doesn't belong." My browser is the Brave browser on Windows 10.

Comment: @galacticninja Due to an unrelated experiment I was running, the server hosting Toasty has been IP-banned from chat. Toasty will be offline until I can get it fixed, which will hopefully be soon. Sorry about the inconvenience!

Comment: @galacticninja Toasty is now back online

Comment: Thanks! I've added a chat room.

Comment: "Better" apparently offers comparison to my competing offer, [Sloshy the Thawman.](https://stackapps.com/questions/8999/sloshy-the-thawman-a-simple-bot-for-keeping-stackoverflow-exchange-chat-rooms) I have to say having two bots for the same purpose is an unhappy situation; we should probably coordinate to let one or the other take over.

Comment: It should be possible to see which rooms it is guarding without creating a login.